# Tripwire local passphrase doesn't work, how do I reset it?

Tags: security

my tripwire local passphrase does not work any more (no idea why) and I want to reset it. How can I do this? I still have the system passphrase (hopefully)

Open Source Tripwire(R) 2.4.2.2.2 built for i686-pc-linux-gnu

Open Source Tripwire 2.4 Portions copyright 2000 Tripwire, Inc. Tripwire is a registered

Answer (score 3):

When I recently installed tripwire I did enter the passphrase wrong, then the dialog below was displayed. Perhaps a hint?

```
If you have completely forgotten your site passphrase, generate a new site key with a new passphrase by running
   twadmin -m G -S /etc/tripwire/site.key
then run 
   dpkg-reconfigure tripwire
```

(I guess reconfigure is not needed if you just want to reset the passphrase.)

Answer (score 1):

When I installed Tripwire automatically from Software Centre on 12.04 64 bit, I saw the stage at which one sets up the local key. I missed any passphrase entry there may have been.
Consequently, I found that only supplying an empty string enabled the --init process to commence.
Security nightmare I know, but purely to get you through, and until you can regenerate it, try entering nothing.

Comment: i hate that trick, took me a while.. thank you for saving me..

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can only reset the tripwire passphrase by re-running the install script. I would assume the script will over write most or all of the configuration files / logs so you might want to make a back up of any that are in clear text.